# Opening a browser and inputting data using python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to do the following using python 2.7:

1. Open a browser
2. Write in a input box and press OK

Comment: What has stopped you? I ask because your question doesn't show signs that you have read the "[*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" article of the help area. You've not stated what you have tried, what problems you have faced in doing so, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need Selenium using Python bindings

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org

Comment: This is the correct answer, but if you just post a link you're going to get downvoted. At least quote a sample program.